# Needing clarity on auto return type deduction for friend operator+ in a class template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++17, auto

I'm just wanting some clarity here with what is happening with this code and why it is behaving as such:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

#include "Register.h"

int main() {
    using namespace vpc;

    Reg8 r8{ 0xEF };

    Reg16 expected{ 478 };
    Reg16 r16a = r8 + r8;
    Reg16 r16b{ r8 + r8 };
    std::cout << expected << r16a << r16b;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The code in my main function doesn't change as it is the same for both cases:

---

This is my `operator+` that I'm working on and this was my first attempt:

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
auto operator+(const Register<Lhs>& l, const Register<Rhs>& r) {
    auto tmp = l.value + r.value;
    if (sizeof(l.value) < sizeof(r.value))
        return Register<Rhs>{ tmp };
    else
        return Register<Lhs>{ tmp };
}
```

And this was the program's output:

**Output v1**

```
Reg16(478)
Prev: 0
hex: 0x01DE
bin: 0000000111011110

Reg16(222)
Prev: 0
hex: 0x00DE
bin: 0000000011011110

Reg16(222)
Prev: 0
hex: 0x00DE
bin: 0000000011011110
```

As you can see above the expected value should be `478` in decimal or `0x01DE` in hex. However the `operator=` and the `Register<T>` constructors are not getting the appropriate value from the `operator+` in this case.

---

I was able to resolve this issue by changing my `operator+` to this:

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
auto operator+(const Register<Lhs>& l, const Register<Rhs>& r) {
    return Register<decltype(l.value + r.value)>{ l.value + r.value };
}
```

And this is giving me the correct result:

**Output v2**

```
Reg16(478)
Prev: 0
hex: 0x01DE
bin: 0000000111011110

Reg16(478)
Prev: 0
hex: 0x01DE
bin: 0000000111011110

Reg16(478)
Prev: 0
hex: 0x01DE
bin: 0000000111011110
```

---

If you need to see my full class implementation you can find it below my question(s) - concern(s): I'm looking for clarity and a better understanding of the behaviors here.

What I would like to know is why is the first version not producing the correct or expected value and why the second attempt does. What are the main differences between the two implementations as well as what is going on under the hood with in the compiler? I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

---

**Register.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <cassert>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace vpc {
    using u8  = std::uint8_t;
    using u16 = std::uint16_t;
    using u32 = std::uint32_t;
    using u64 = std::uint64_t;

    template<typename T>
    struct Register;

    using Reg8  = Register<u8>;
    using Reg16 = Register<u16>;
    using Reg32 = Register<u32>;
    using Reg64 = Register<u64>;

    template<typename T>
    struct Register {
        T value;
        T previous_value;
        std::bitset<sizeof(T)* CHAR_BIT> bits;

        Register() : value{ 0 }, previous_value{ 0 }, bits{ 0 } {}

        template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(U) > sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
        explicit Register(const U val, const u8 idx = 0) :
            value{ static_cast<T>((val >> std::size(bits) * idx) &
                  std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max()) },
            previous_value{ 0 },
            bits{ value }
        {
            constexpr u16 sizeT = sizeof(T);
            constexpr u16 sizeU = sizeof(U);
            assert((idx >= 0) && (idx <= ((sizeU / sizeT) - 1)) );
        }

        template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(U) < sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
        explicit Register(const U val, const u8 idx = 0) :
            value{ static_cast<T>((static_cast<T>(val) << sizeof(U)*CHAR_BIT*idx) &
                  std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max()) },
            previous_value{ 0 },
            bits{ value }
        {
            constexpr u16 sizeT = sizeof(T);
            constexpr u16 sizeU = sizeof(U);
            assert((idx >= 0) && (idx <= ((sizeT / sizeU) - 1)) );
        }

        template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(U) == sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
        explicit Register(const U val, const u8 idx = 0) :
            value{ static_cast<T>( val ) }, previous_value{ 0 }, bits{ value }
        {}

        template<typename... Args>
        Register(Args... args) {}

        template<typename U>
        Register(const Register<U>& reg, const u8 idx = 0) : Register(reg.value, idx) {}

        void changeEndian() {
            T tmp = value;
            char* const p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tmp);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T) / 2; ++i)
                std::swap(p[i], p[sizeof(T) - i - 1]);
            bits = tmp;
        }

        Register& operator=(const Register& obj) {
            this->value = obj.value;
            this->previous_value = obj.previous_value;
            this->bits = obj.bits;
            return *this;
        }

        template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
        friend auto operator+(const Register<Lhs>& l, const Register<Rhs>& r);
    };
} // namespace vpc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points.

(1) Remember to use `if constexpr`, instead of simply `if`, in your first version of `operator+ ()`

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
auto operator+(const Register<Lhs>& l, const Register<Rhs>& r) {
    auto tmp = l.value + r.value;
    if constexpr (sizeof(l.value) < sizeof(r.value)) // if constexpr here!
        return Register<Rhs>{ tmp };
    else
        return Register<Lhs>{ tmp };
}
```

otherwise `auto` deduction type doesn't works when `sizeof(l.value)` is different from `sizeof(r.value)`.

(2) From your first version of `operator()` (that works because you sum two value of the same type) you have an overflow.

More exactly:

- `Lhs` and `Rhs` are `std::uint8_t` so the function return a `Register<std::uint8_t>`.
- `tmp` become `std::uint32_t` (see point 3) but assigning it to a `std::uint8_t` loose the overflow

(3) From my platform, from the code

```
std::cout << sizeof(char) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(std::declval<char>()+std::declval<char>()) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(short) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(std::declval<short>()+std::declval<short>()) << std::endl;
```

I get

```
1
4
2
4
```

It's called "integral promotion".

In short: the sum of two `char` become a `int`; the sum of two `short` become a `int`.

This should clarify why works (but not exactly as you want, I suppose) your second version of `operator+ ()`

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
auto operator+(const Register<Lhs>& l, const Register<Rhs>& r) {
    return Register<decltype(l.value + r.value)>{ l.value + r.value };
}
```

You have that `decltype(l.value + r.value)` is `int`; so that `decltype(R8+R8)` is a `R32`.

Comment: Now I understand why I wasn't getting `0x01DE` because of truncation with in the first version and by using `decltype` in the second version it will automatically promote to a larger type if possible. Thank you for the detailed explanation. It was something that I had just overlooked. It always helps to have a second pair of eyes! This is why I was asking for clarity. I was suspecting something going on but wasn't able to pinpoint it. I do know about truncation of values and integer promotion, but it wasn't staring me in the face so to speak!

Comment: @FrancisCugler - The bad part is that I had forgotten the "integral promotion" part; is something that I know twenty or more year ago (I was programming in C, at the time). So is useful also for me.

Comment: I've given some thought but I think I prefer your answer only to the fact that you explain things in a little more detail and that you also give the advice of using `constexpr` within the first version.

Answer (score 1):

What are `Rhs` and `Lhs` when

```
r8 + r8
```

is called? Both are `uint8_t`, so in first version

```
auto tmp = l.value + r.value;
if (sizeof(l.value) < sizeof(r.value))
    return Register<Rhs>{ tmp };
else
    return Register<Lhs>{ tmp };
```

temporary `tmp = 478` is passed to `Register` whose `value` type is `uint8_t`, and you lose data.

---

In second version

```
return Register<decltype(l.value + r.value)>{ l.value + r.value };
```

you are using `decltype` to get type of `l.value + r.value`. Both types are `uint_8`, but while performing integer operation both are promoted to `int`, so `decltype()` returns `int`, width of `int` is enough to store 478.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but everything you stated here was described by another. I don't know who answered first so I gave you both an up vote! As I commented before; sometimes you need a second pair of eyes! The truncation of value in the first version wasn't staring at me directly, and with the `decltype` in the second version it was automatically doing integer promotion.

Comment: @FrancisCugler - rafix07 was the first. For a handful of minutes but was the first.